# WPF c# Checkbox clickable area modification - BATCH

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox

I have about 3000 instances of checkboxes that are styled in a way which you can click the entire row and the state of the checkboxes will change.

How do you modify the checkbox so that ONLY the box is click able. I did a good amount of search and arrived at no conclusion.

Thanks

Comment: Post your current XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you must do is check which element has been clicked.

In the first solution you should check if OriginalSource is `BulletChrome` and if it is, you should allow CheckBox to change state, by setting:  `e.Handled = false;`. If you don't allow to change CheckBox state you should set `e.Handled` to true.

In the second solution you should check if OriginalSource is `Border` or `Path` and to make sure that the appropriate element was clicked, we should check names.

You can use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event, to determine OriginalSource.

XAML:

```
<CheckBox Content="test" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is BulletChrome)
        e.Handled = false;
    else
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or you can create your own CheckBox ControlTemplate ([msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

You should check in `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event OriginalSource and allow or deny change CheckBox state.

Example with `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle 
        Margin="15,0,0,0"
        StrokeThickness="1"
        Stroke="#60000000"
        StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"    Value="{StaticResource CheckBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="BulletDecorator_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Border x:Name="chbStyleBorder"  
                              Width="13" 
                              Height="13" 
                              CornerRadius="0" 
                              Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="1"
                              BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}">
                                <Path 
                                    Width="7" Height="7" 
                                    x:Name="chbStyleCheckMark"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                                    Stroke="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                    StrokeThickness="2"
                                    Data="M 0 0 L 7 7 M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                            </Border>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleCheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleCheckMark" Property="Data" Value="M 0 7 L 7 0" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PressedBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="chbStyleBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void BulletDecorator_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.OriginalSource is Border && ((Border)e.OriginalSource).Name == "chbStyleBorder") || (e.OriginalSource is Path && ((Path)e.OriginalSource).Name == "chbStyleCheckMark"))
        e.Handled = false;
    else
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further, I am relatively new to WPF. Where do I create such template? and how does the code-behind link to the xaml here as they function is not a default event handler?  Thanks

Comment: @user2584960 check my answer again:), 1) There, where you want to apply this style e.g. in Windows resources. 2) In XAML, you will create new ControlTemplate, so you can add event handler to every element which is using.

Comment: after I implemented this, the box and the text both disappeared.

Comment: Thanks~ It worked perfectly!  But now the look of the box changed from the default "white and gray". I tried to change the border to match the old style but arrived at no conclusion, any advice?