# Is it possible to override a control's event handler globally?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have about 3000 checkboxes that I would like to have their "PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" event handled differently. Is it possible to override the default event handler for all checkboxes globally?

Comment: Don't you want *different* handling, per your question? How can you handle the checkboxes in one place then? And 3000 checkboxes, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the OP just meant "different from the default/standard behavior" not "different from each other." I could be wrong though.

Comment: This is a derived question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663082/wpf-c-sharp-checkbox-clickable-area-modification-batch

The template provided changes the appearances of the checkbox, so I cannot proceed with solution 2. Therefore I wanted to use solution 1 and globally override previewmouseleftbuttondown to only handle the click when the box is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Checkbox.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx) is a Routed Event.  This means you can assign a common event handler within a parent of the tree, and handle the events "globally" however you choose.

For details, see [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), in particular, the section titled ["Singular Handler Attachment Points"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing), which deals with this scenario.

Comment: +1 The [Event Setters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#events_styles) section may also be an alternative approach, you can define a global style that applies to check boxes to attach the event handler specifically to check boxes